# Создание функции форматирования строки в MySql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, функции

В одной таблице есть `Фамилия`, `Имя`, `Отчество` студента. Вопрос. Как сделать функцию чтобы  отображались все три столбца в формате `Фамилия.А.А.` (инициалы).

И затем отобразить в связанной таблице.

Comment: Если вы говорите о функции, то почему речь о трех столбцах, функция возвращает одно значение и три столбца она сделать ну никак не может. Что то типа `concat(фамилия,'.',subtr(имя,1,1),'.',substr(отчество,1,1),'.')` должна вернуть примерно то что вы видимо хотите. Но вот что означает "отобразить в связанной таблице", ума не приложу, в таблицу можно записать и из нее можно прочитать, "отобразить" нет такого понятия. И связанной кстати по какому критерию

Comment: @Mike если честно я сам не до конца понимаю, что от меня требуют. Нам сказали так.
 Создать функцию формирования строки с фамилией и инициалами вида "Фамилия И.О." на основе данных о фамилии, имени и отчестве.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом. Для выполнения запроса нужно в клиенте установить разделитель //, например, в консольном mysql-клиенте это осуществляется при помощи команды `DELIMITER //`

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fio//
CREATE FUNCTION fio(
  `name`       TEXT CHARSET utf8,
  `surname`    TEXT CHARSET utf8,
  `patronymic` TEXT CHARSET utf8
)
RETURNS TEXT CHARSET utf8
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  RETURN CONCAT(
    `surname`,
    ' ',
    SUBSTRING(`name`, 1, 1),
    '. ',
    SUBSTRING(`patronymic`, 1, 1),
    '.');
END//
```

Воспользоваться функцией можно так

```
SELECT
  fio(name, surname, patronymic)
FROM
  users;
```

Comment: Что означает EXISTS в if?

Comment: Проверка существует ли функция, если попробовать удалить несуществующую функцию - будет сгенерирована ошибка.

Comment: Можно ли вместо двойного слеша точку с запятой? Что будет если я не буду записывать первую строку?

Comment: Вы не сможете тогда использовать точку с запятой внутри функции, а как минимум одна точка с запятой в теле функции вам потребуется.

Comment: DELIMITER действует только в текущем запросе или на последующие тоже?

Comment: На самом деле DELIMITER - это команда mysql, она действует на все запросы, пока вы не отмените ее действие новым вызовом, например, DELIMITER ; Только следует помнить, что другие клиенты могут по-другому устанавливать разделитель, например, у phpMyAdmin для этого предназначено отдельное текстовое поле.

Comment: Прошу прощение,а в SqlServere код остаётся аналогичным?Можете привести пример,если это не так.

Comment: Боюсь, не будет работать. Лучше завести новый вопрос под диалект MS SQL.