# Создание функции форматирования строки в MS SQL Server

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, функции

Интересно узнать, каков будет формат [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528653/180600) ответа в данном варианте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если все три текстовых поля в одной таблице, и функция форматирования нужна только для этой таблицы, то, на мой взгляд, проще всего реализовать это с помощью *computed column* (вычисляемый столбец):

```
create table Students
(
    FirstName nvarchar(50) not NULL,
    LastName nvarchar(50) not NULL,
    MiddleName nvarchar(50) not NULL,
    FullName as LastName + ' ' + left(FirstName, 1) + '.' + left(MiddleName, 1) + '.'
)
```

Тогда при выборке достаточно просто указать имя вычисляемого столбца:

```
select FullName
from Students
```

Вычисление `FullName` будет происходить при обращении к этому столбцу. Также при создании таблицы можно пометить вычисляемый столбец ключевым словом `persisted`:

```
FullName as ... persisted
```

В этом случае его значение будет храниться в таблице, и перевычисляться при изменении данных в исходных столбцах. При выборке вычисление происходить не будет, а будет доставаться вычисленное сохранённое значение.

Также можно реализовать и через функцию (например, если столбцы не в одной таблице, или это однотипным образом будет применяться к нескольким похожим таблицам). Для применения в запросе к нескольким строкам *inline* табличная функция будет выгоднее, чем скалярная. Пример такой функции для данного случая:

```
create function dbo.tfFullName
(
    @firstName nvarchar(50),
    @lastName nvarchar(50),
    @middleName nvarchar(50)
)
returns table
as return
    select
        FullName = @lastName + ' ' + left(@firstName, 1) + '.' + left(@middleName, 1) + '.'
GO
```

Использование:

```
select f.FullName
from Students s
    cross apply dbo.tfFullName(s.FirstName, s.LastName, s.MiddleName) f
GO
```